# Connecting Bluetooth Headphones to PC fails to find drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect Voberry IPX7 headphones to my Windows 7 PC via a bluetooth 4.0 USB-adapter.
They get recognized, but when Windows Update tries to find drivers for the "bluetooth-headphones" it fails to find any.

The headphones are called "EK-68", but that name won't yield any google results for those headphones.
On the packaging the chipset is specified as "CSR8635".

The headphones use bluetooth 4.1 + EDR and the adapter uses 4.0, but I was told bluetooth was backwards compatible and I doubt that's the issue.

Is there any way I can get them to work regardless?

I'm afraid as the headphones were intended for use with mobile devices support for PC was never considered. If nothing else I'd like to understand why they work with any modern mobile device, but not with a Windows 7 PC. Would this imply they'd work under Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue. It is related to bluetooth device drivers. My search showed me how people fixed their issue and it was all about installing some drivers + possibly a hack to add a serial port device.

So I checked in my adapter driver setting that manufacturer is Cambridge Silicon Radio. Searching for it I found some additional audio profiles in [windows catalog update](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Cambridge%20Silicon%20Radio). Namely `CSR plc - Audio - Bluetooth Hands-free Audio Device`.

After installing this catalog using the `pnputil -a extracted_cab/*.inf` connecting headphones lead to all functions being recognized instead of seeing devices without drivers in file manager. Extracting cab you can do by opening in explorer, copy the files and paste in normal dir.